# Stumpy: Example of finding top-k motifs not working

Tags: stumpy

I am trying to recreate the example shown in https://github.com/TDAmeritrade/stumpy/discussions/438.

Stumpy 1.11.1 seems to find just 1 motif; the size of the returned inde in the call to stumpy.motifs() is (1, 10).

Can someone please help?

Running the code that produces two motifs (for the person entering / leaving the room) does not result in 2 motifs: only the first motif is returned.

Comment: The example works correctly on Stumpy 1.9.1.

Comment: Please see https://github.com/TDAmeritrade/stumpy/discussions/794